# MapStruct, Lombok, nested type and one mapping for a specific field

Tags: spring, lombok, mapstruct

Question as follows, I have a DTO and a Result class. They mirror each other in terms of the most of the fields, but for one specific I have added a

```
@Named("f")
default Integer getValueForCustomField(Integer input) {...}
```

It seems to work, BUT before I add a `@Mapping`, which refers that nested type, all fields of that sub-type are resolved by default. The moment I add

```
@Mapping(target = "nested", source = "dto.nestedData", qualifierByName = "f")
```

The generated mapper no longer covers all other fields of that subtype (and commenting that Mapping restores the behavior).

Is these a way to have both? I can manually go around every field and create a `@Mapping` for it, but I would like to avoid that.

Side note, had issues with Lombok's `@Builder`, so ended up using

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", builder = @Builder (disableBuilder = true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that

```
@Mapping(source = "nested", target = "nested")
```

solved my problem